# How to make the rendering process less resource consuming

Tags: rendering

I am new to blender and I really love it. I have completed some tutorials from tutor4u on youtube. I have a HP Probook 4530s with a core i5 2430M CPU and the problem is that when rendering files the CPU temps reach about 99C or about 210F which It think is not good.I have tried limiting the threads to 1 but then one of the core heats up to 200F or 95C.
P.S. I am not sure if my computer has a graphics card. It does have Intel Integrated Graphics.

Comment: If your CPU is getting too hot (to the point it is damaged), it means you don't have sufficient cooling.

Comment: Another thing you can do is limit the number of threads blender can use. This  only applies to multi-core CPUs of course. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15248/599

Comment: Modern CPUs throttle (reduce clock frequency) that means you loose performance, unmount the fan and remove any remaining heat paste. See this HowTo: http://www.wikihow.com/Apply-Thermal-Paste

Comment: I can't open my laptop. I don't know how and I don't want to risk it.