# How to restrict to cycles use only 90% of gpu?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

How to restrict to cycles use only 90% of gpu? For example redshift use always between 80-90% and because of that i can work with something else when render on video card. But when i put render on cycles i can forgot about using PC while rendering.

Comment: Apparently my rep is too low for a comment. Which I would have prefered to do. As this is something of a duplicate question. The limiting process is explained [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15247/how-to-configure-blender-so-that-it-uses-only-50-of-total-cpu-when-rendering).

Comment: I don't think is a duplicate at all. That thread refers to the CPU, not limiting the GPU.

Comment: You should really let the computer work. Rendering is one of the most demanding tasks for a computer. Unless you have a very powerful one multitasking will be limited...

Answer (score 3):

From the Blende manual on [GPU Rendering](http://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html)

> Why is Blender unresponsive during rendering?
>
> While a graphics card is
>   rendering, it can not redraw the user interface, which makes Blender
>   unresponsive. We attempt to avoid this problem by giving back control
>   over the GPU as often as possible, but a completely smooth interaction
>   can’t be guaranteed, especially on heavy scenes. This is a limitation
>   of graphics cards for which no true solution exists, though we might
>   be able to improve this somewhat in the future.
>
> **If possible, it is best to install more than one GPU, using one for display and the other(s) for rendering.**

Comment: i consider - if others gpu renders can be responsive (in my example redshift in maya - while redshift ipr rendering maya fully functional) during rendering then in blender must be some options....well if so in cycles then i will hope developers add this (in redshift for example devs somehow control gpu usage in 80-90% load) in future...