# Baking cloth simulation use only 20% of cpu ressources, how to get 100%?

Tags: baking

Baking a cloth use only 20% of CPU, inactive process of cpu is 78%, is there a way to use those extra 78% ?
Blender 2.75
Windows 10

[image: task manager]

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/27316/599

Comment: Blender physics are not multi-threaded. You can use Houdini for FREE for non-commercial stuff or $200 licence for commercial, which you will get back soon through time this app will save doing your simulations.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have a quad core? Simulation calculations are not multithreaded, and so cannot use more than 1 core at once. If it's using up a single core of your quad core, that'd be your 20-25%. There is no way to increase this unless someone gets a multithreaded physics algorithm into blender (these exist, but they are complicated and there are caveats. The program Marvelous Designer has multi core cloth sim, and maybe some other expensive programs.)

However, you could run multiple entirely separate physics bakes, or bake physics while rendering or performing other tasks.

Comment: Thanks again @Drudje )))        yes i use a i7-4980HQ CPU with 4 cores (8 logical cores).    But ive been reading a few post here with the opposite problem, they where using 100% and wanted to lower it to 50% or so...did they had a single core ???

Comment: It's impossible to know what their issue was without knowing their setup, but perhaps?

Comment: @Drudje  my mistake, it was for rendering and not baking (((                               http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15247/how-to-configure-blender-so-that-it-uses-only-50-of-total-cpu-when-rendering