# How to accelerate cloth simulation

Tags: cycles-render-engine, physics, rigid-body-simulation, windows

Anyone knows how I can make my animation generate faster on the viewport? More exactly, when I try to simulate cloth for example, just 14-20% of my CPU is used, and to preview animation it's slower.... How can I make blender use 100% of CPU when it do that simulation?

Comment: read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35803/baking-cloth-simulation-use-only-20-of-cpu-ressources-how-to-get-100 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27125/is-physics-calculation-multithreading-possible

Comment: I think we should mark this as a duplicate and move on.