# cloth simulation lag, and lag in general

Tags: cloth-simulation

Hello :) hope you're good !

I have some lag in blender and I want to ask you if is it the fault of my computer or can i change it.
So i start a cloth simulation of a subdivided plane with 12300 vertices. And when i play the simulation it goes at like 0.5 FPS. the quality steps for the cloth is set to 5. Self collision enable.

And in general in find my blender slow at some point.

So my config is : Ryzen 7 3700x 3.6/4.4Ghz + RTX 2070 8Go VRam + 32Go Ram + SSD

Please tell me what is wrong with this.

Thank's for all :)

Comment: Hey, nice rig :). Regarding the cloth simulation, there's not much you can do. It is slow because it only uses *one* of your CPU cores (and no GPU). Self-collision is also very compute-intensive. You can try disabling self-collision until needed, and bake the simulation cache to remove the lag...

Comment: Similar thread here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/35803/78972

Comment: Ok thank's for the answer 
So i will bake my animation