# How can I minimize cpu process without effecting the quality? (MacBook Pro)

Tags: gpu, osx, hardware

I am a MacBook Pro user (15-inch, 2019) and I found out that my device is not a good choice for 3d design. Until I purchase a fine device for this purpose I need to work with it. Do you have any suggestions on how I can reduce the CPU workload in Blender without affecting the quality? my processor is a 2,3 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9. Sometimes the workload is too much that my screen turns off. I would appreciate any suggestions. Also, my device has two graphic processors, one is Radeon Pro 560X 4 GB and the other is Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB. But from what I learned online blender doesn't work with it. Does switching it make a better result? and if yes which one do you suggest?

Comment: Check answers here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15247/how-to-configure-blender-so-that-it-uses-only-50-of-total-cpu-when-rendering