# Where is the option for setting number of CPU threads

Tags: rendering, settings

[This post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15247/how-to-configure-blender-so-that-it-uses-only-50-of-total-cpu-when-rendering#answer-15248), and [this documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/render_settings/performance.html) implies (and has a picture of) setting the number of threads used by blender for rendering. However when I look where I think the post is pointing to I don't see the same settings. The documentation says the settings are under the Panel "Render" -> "Performance" but what I think it means by that is called "Render Settings" and the "Performance" tab has no such settings. Where is this setting located?

[image]

Comment: I think that is only available if you have CPU enabled in preferences system tab and only for cycles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking in the right place, but you can't see it because your rendering mode is set to Eevee and this feature is only available in Cycles.

[image: Cycles Performance Settings]